# Как извлечь $parameters из метода __callStatic() для последующего преобразования в строку при помощи метода __ToString()?

Tags: php, ооп

```
class Concatenator
{
    private static $string = [];

    public static function __callStatic($method, $parameters)
    {   
        self::$string = $parameters;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return str_replace(' ', '+', strtolower(self::$string));
    }
}

$concatenated = Concatenator::prepareString('I am concatenated');

echo $concatenated;
```

Не могу понять, как передать массив, хранящийся self::$string в магический метод __toString().

Answer (score 2):

Не знаю зачем вам это но все таки.

**Ошибка 1** Ваш метод `__callStatic()` не возвращает ничего, соответственно в выражении

`$concatenated = Concatenator::prepareString('I am concatenated');`

`$concatenated` равен `null`

**Ошибка 2**

```
  public function __toString()
  {
    return str_replace(' ', '+', strtolower(implode(',', self::$string)));
  }
```

Свойство `$string` это массив, его нужно преобразовать в строку, к примеру через `implode` после чего применить ее к `strtolower`.

Ниже готовый вариант класса

```
class Concatenator
{
  private static $string = [];

  public static function __callStatic($method, $parameters)
  {
    self::$string = $parameters;

    return new static();
  }

  public function __toString()
  {
    return str_replace(' ', '+', strtolower(implode(',', self::$string)));
  }
}

$concatenated = Concatenator::prepareString('I am concatenated');


echo $concatenated;
```